# Clover credit card payment token

Tags: c#, clover, clover-payment

I want to integrate clover payment api into my application. I have successfully created orders but in payment section I am unable to get payment token as clover is using RSA encryption, unfortunately there is no any way given in detail. I need to generate card token in c#.

Comment: https://docs.clover.com/docs/ecommerce-generating-a-card-token

Comment: @Chetan I have seen the documentation but they are giving only java example. However, I have to do it in c#